# Ubuntu Kernel 5.7 Toggles USB-Serial XR21B1424 RTS# GPIOD7/RS485D on RS485 Transmit But Later Versions do Not (e.g. 5.17)

Tags: usb

Ubuntu Kernel 5.7 using cdc-acm USB/Serial for Maxlinear XR21B1424, toggles that chip's GPIOD7/RS485D high during transmit and low at all other times for half-duplex control, but later kernel(s) e.g. Kernel 5.17 (uses xr_serial USB/Serial for Maxlinear XR21B1424) does not. How can one tell if there was an update to the kernel driver that keeps XR21B1424's GPIOD7/RS485D line high or in a pullup state always ?

Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS, Kernel 5.7: During transmit, GPIOD7/RS485D is toggled high, then kept low

Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS, Kernel 5.17, GPIOD7/RS485D is high always, transmit output is inhibited when rtscts=1

Ubuntu 23.10.1, Kernel 6.5.0-14-generic (in VirtualBox/Windows) UART transmits, but GPIOD7/RS485D is kept high always

```
import time
import serial
import serial.rs485

myPort = '/dev/ttyUSB2'

ser = serial.rs485.RS485(
port=myPort,
baudrate=4800,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
xonxoff=0,
rtscts=0,
timeout=1)

ser.rs485_mode = serial.rs485.RS485Settings(loopback = False, rts_level_for_tx = True, rts_level_for_rx = False)

myString = "This is an example of a string that is written to the serial Port"

myArray = myString.encode('utf-8')
print("Writing " +  str("'") + myString + str("'"))

ser.write(myArray)
ser.read(10)
ser.close
```

Comment: Please provide specific details of which version of Ubuntu you have installed.

Comment: 'Working' version: 20.04.6 LTS (with kernel 5.7.0-050700-generic).

'Not working' version: 20.04.6 LTS (with kernel 5.15.0-89-generic).

Will work to provide data regarding latest or later version of Ubuntu also...

Comment: 23.10.1 Under VirtualBox/Windows10 Same Issue.

Comment: This is a question more about the driver configuration of the USB serial chip but wondering if and how the GPIOD7/RS485D pin can be configured to toggle high when the chip transmits, even if that's done forcibly by the application.  Thanks

Comment: Same issue:  Linux Ubuntu-20 5.15.0-91-generic #101~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 16 14:22:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Version(s) of the kernel after 5.7 but prior to 5.15 or starting at 5.15 use the xr_serial_driver.  The cdc-acm driver used by 5.7 kernel was later changed to exclude supporting Exar type USB serial devices.  The cdc-acm driver left the Maxlinear chip in a default state, which enables RTS/CTS flow control and where GPIO7 is set as active high auto RS-485 half-duplex control.

Comment: I found this, which probably will resolve the issue:  
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/johan/usb-serial.git/commit/?h=usb-next&id=974e2f6a0554685493cc44406bc7d8ba0a3b0e33

Answer (score 0):

The new xr_serial driver that replaced cdc_acm does not enable the 'RS485' mode that asserts GPIO7/RS485 during T/X by default as the old, cdc_acm driver originally did.

The xr_serial driver in Ubuntu-V20 5.15.0-91-generic #101~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 16 14:22:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), leaves GPIO7/RS485 in the chip's default state, which is a GPIO, and will not assert during T/X.

In order to enable the functionality, either the older, cdc_acm, or an updated or modified driver must be used to enable this configuration.